# Is there a way to have multiple line detail in ErrorTextField?

Tags: cosmicmind

I have a problem with long text in detail for ErrorTextField.
Is there's a way to fixed this issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `textField.detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

:) All the best!